# OGX.JS How to have multiple mouse/touch events?

Tags: javascript, ogx.js

I'm trying to get the distance after a touch/mouse move over 2 separate elements in OGX.JS. I use the built in touch dist, which works

```
 this.touch.dist.set({
      target: '.box1',
      cb_move: function(obj){ ... }
 });
```

But how to I add another one? If I add another instance like that, it just overwrites the first one.

```
this.touch.dist.set({
      target: '.box2',
      cb_move: function(obj){ ... }
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create another instance of `touch.dist`, which is an instance of `OGX.Touches.Move`.

```
 //default instance
 this.touch.dist.set({
     target: '.box1',
     cb_move: function(obj){ ... }
 });
 this.touch.dist.enable();

 //create new instance
 this.touch.dist2 = new OGX.Touches.Move(this);
 this.touch.dist2.set({
     target: '.box2',
     cb_move: function(obj){ ... }
 });
 this.touch.dist2.enable();
```

Then you have to disable the instances when leaving the view, inside the view, do

```
 this.disable = function(){
     this.touch.dist.disable();
     this.touch.dist2.disable();
 };
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but when I'm leaving the view and come back, it doesn't work anymore? Please help

Comment: You have to disable your touch instances, either in destroy or disable. Will edit reply.

Comment: You're welcome, note that in the next release (1.19) you won't have to enable/disable anymore with the state flag set to auto (I'm the main person behind of this project)